# Hovering over two DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div (headline) and another div (button) that appears when you hover over the headline. When you leave the headline, the button should disappear.

In my current code the button disappears when you move your cursor to it. Do you have any ideas how to keep the button displayed when you hover over headline or button, so that the button is clickable?

Thanks.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L6jtotog/

CSS:

```
.headline {
    background-color: grey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 70%;
    position: relative;
}

#button{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="headline" onmouseover="func(true)" onmouseout="func(false)">Headline 1 <div id="button">Test</div></div>
```

JS:

```
function func(showPanel) {
    if(showPanel) {
        $("#button").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#button").hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using something like that, you can do everything with **CSS alone**!

```css
.headline {
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 70%;
  position: relative;
}

#button{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: -50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.headline:hover #button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="headline">
    Headline 1
    <div id="button">Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your case, when you need to go to `Test`, it calls the `mouseout` which cancels the hover. So I gave an extra padding. Now you can go over the text.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the position attribute of `#button` to absolute, `position:absolute;`
it makes the browser think that `#button` is outside of the `div` `.headline`
That is why when the mouse cursor reaches over `#button`, the browser actually thinks it is outside the `.headline` and thus, invokes the `onmouseout` function.
This is why you are getting this problem.

You might want to remove `position:absolute` from `#button` and use `position:relative`.